# How to edit and save a reactive form in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I have built a reactive form, and persisting the data, at initial step I would be saving the form with initial set of data.

for eg:- I have an array of objects as below :

```
[{Name:'Tom',age:'25',subject:'maths'}].
```

On saving this to DB, I will be getting a unique ID, Say Student ID.. By using this ID I would need to edit the Data..

Could you please help me how I should be editing the data and save back

P.S., I have a data service where I will be temporarily storing the data and getting the data.

Comment: What you have tried so far! You seem to describe your requirement rather than a specific problem your facing. this example: https://embed.plnkr.co/ZwQB5EENaR7wYdMA2rDs/ would help I guess.

Comment: i have persisted the data to the database where i have got a unique ID for that particular record, now how can i edit the same record using the unique ID